# How to put all Activator in same context while using karaf and hazelcast jet?

Tags: java, osgi, hazelcast, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am creating one application in which I am using java 17,Spring Boot, karaf for osgi and hazelcast jet as doing some join for data coming from different sources(modules) but as using Hazelcast Jet module cannot identified by the ServiceReference they are the getting registered in different references, So how register them in one context.

My Common module interface which used in different modules (packaging as jar in all modules):

```
public interface DataService {
    String name();
    public BatchStage<Object> getData(Pipeline pipeline, Map<String, Object> source);
}
```

First Module here we implement the above interface:

```
public class JDBCDataSource implements DataService, Serializable {
         public BatchStage<Object> getData(Pipeline pipeline, Map<String, Object> source) {
          //Hazelcast Jdbc implementation
       }
    }
```

And Activator for First module:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
 public static BundleContext bundleContext;
 ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
 @Override
 public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
   Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
  appContext = SpringApplication.run(Activator.class);
  bundleContext = context;
  registerServices();
 }
 @Override
 public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
  bundleContext = null;
  SpringApplication.exit(appContext, () -> 0);
 }
 public static BundleContext getBundleContext() {
  return bundleContext;
 }
 private void registerServices() {
  DataService  service = new JDBCDataSource();
  bundleContext.registerService(DataService.class.getName(), service, new HashMap<String, Object>());
  System.out.println("Service registered: " + service.name());
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Activator.class, args);
 }
}
```

And one rest controller in First Module via which we fetch all services

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
@Component
public class RController {
public Map<String, Object> fetchRecordsPipline() {
   BundleContext bundleContext = Activator.getBundleContext();

            Collection<ServiceReference<DataService>> references = bundleContext
                    .getServiceReferences(DataService.class, null);
            for (ServiceReference<DataService> reference : references) {
                DataService calcService = bundleContext.getService(reference);
                System.out.println(calcService.name());

            }

}
}
```

Same way second Module here we implement the above interface:

```
public class JsonDataSource implements DataService, Serializable {
         public BatchStage<Object> getData(Pipeline pipeline, Map<String, Object> source) {
          //Hazelcast json implementation
       }
    }
```

And Activator for Second module:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
 public static BundleContext bundleContext;
 ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
 @Override
 public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
   Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
  appContext = SpringApplication.run(Activator.class);
  bundleContext = context;
  registerServices();
 }
 @Override
 public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
  bundleContext = null;
  SpringApplication.exit(appContext, () -> 0);
 }
 public static BundleContext getBundleContext() {
  return bundleContext;
 }
 private void registerServices() {
  DataService  service = new JsonDataSource();
  bundleContext.registerService(DataService.class.getName(), service, new HashMap<String, Object>());
  System.out.println("Service registered: " + service.name());
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Activator.class, args);
 }
}
```

Hazelcast jet Instance in generated in First Module.

Now we run it in karaf both the modules are getting registered and when we call rest controller request it is only fetching First module from the **Collection<ServiceReference>** "JDBC Service" only not "Json Service" but both the service are registered properly in karaf, as per my understanding as I am using Hazelcast Jet it causing them to get registered in different context so now how to registered them both in same context(BundleContex/Spring Context) so they can communicate and I can join both sources data?